# Changing the color of a <select> depending on its value - CSS only(?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML select element with some options inside:

```
<select class = "myRed" id="mySelect" onchange="onSelectChange()">
    <option selected value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I would like the text color of the select object to be red when its value is 0, black otherwise. I could be able to do this through JavaScript:

```
function onSelectChange(){
    if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == 0){
        document.getElementById('mySelect').className = 'myRed';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('mySelect').className = 'myBlack'
    }
}
```

where

```
.myRed{color:red;}
```

and

```
.myBlack{color:black;}
```

However, I've been told this is somehow reachable through CSS only, without using JavaScript. I cannot think about any other way than using JS. Could anyone please advise?

Comment: Styling selects is really inconsistent from browser to browser – I normally use something like customselect (http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/) but unlike your question states, this *does* use javascript to create the elements, then a layer of CSS to style them.

Comment: @Oriol thanks for the remark, I wrote it without testing cause JS should be the "avoided" solution this time. Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: @Djave, exactly, I personally cannot figure out how to make it without javascript. But the person who told me this knows his stuffs, so it's worth give a try and see if someone here knows :)

Comment: AFAIK you can't get the current value of the select with CSS. You can get the initially selected `option` with `[selected]`, but it won't be the current one. And even if it was the current one, you would need a parent selector to style the `select`. And even if browsers supported a parent selector, styling a `select` is so unreliable.

Comment: Changing the styling of elements can not be done without JavaScript. CSS is incapable of targeting and changing styles. In the code you provided there is no call to the JavaScript function onSelectChange() you need to add <select class = "myRed" id="mySelect" onChange='onSelectChange();'>.

Comment: @jeff thanks for the remark. As I said to Oriol, I wrote the JS quickly just to give the idea, I omitted the call to the function because my idea was indeed find out if anyhow I could have done through CSS. But you're right, the code seen like that is inconsistent and I fixed it. Thank you

Comment: You should use a js library for change select with other tags and give styles to these other tags because browsers don't support many styles for select jet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `required` and assign empty value to the first option:

```
<select class="mySelect" required>
    <option value="">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

css:

```
.mySelect { font-size: 2em; }
.mySelect option { color: green; }
.mySelect option[value=""] { color: red; }
.mySelect:invalid { color: red; }
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3wmsc8k/)

Answer (score -2):

If you're looking for something simple, you can always do it this way:

.css

```
.myRed{color:red;}
.myBlack{color:black;}
```

.html

```
<select class = "myRed" id="mySelect">
    <option selected value="0" class="myRed">0</option>
    <option value="1" class="myBlack">1</option>
    <option value="2" class="myBlack">2</option>
</select>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyPKoM

Comment: Thank you, this is what I tried already but doesn't get my purpose. This is because the class assigned to the select is always "myRed", so what would be styled in this case are the elements _inside_ the list but the selected element in the select object would always be red (at least, without js) :(

Comment: Yeah, I realized what you meant right after posting that. Sorry!

Comment: This does not work in chrome 98