# Change the 'option' color with the attribute 'disabled'

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to change the font color of an `<option>` with the attribute `disabled`.

I have tried this

```
option:disabled { color: red }
```

and this

```
option[disabled] { color: red }
```

Both work but the color only gets red when you CLICK on the select field. By default it is black. How can I change it?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/y0g0stbb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
    select{
    color:red;
    }
    option{
    color:black;
    }
```

Comment: It's possible to select the disabled.

Answer (score 7):

It can't be both selected and disabled.

```css
option:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected>Choose something</option>
  <option disabled>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

If you want to disable the select, instead of the option you need to moved disabled to the select tag

```css
select:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select disabled>
  <option selected>Choose something</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

The color has to be applied to the `select` element, not the `option`. So, you can do this:

You can use `required` and assign empty value to the first option:

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" disabled>0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

css:

```css
select:invalid { color: red; }
```

If you do this, when the option with empty value is selected, the `select` element will be invalid, and so the above *css* class will trigger.

Solved this thanks to the answer to this post: [Changing the color of a <select> depending on its value - CSS only(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388057/changing-the-color-of-a-select-depending-on-its-value-css-only)

Answer (score 2):

try this, hope it will work:
in html:

```
    <select>
      <option value="">Choose something</option>
       <option disabled="disabled" value="" class="red">1</option>
       <option disabled="disabled" value="" class="red">2</option>
       <option disabled="disabled" value="" class="red">3</option>
    </select>
```

in CSS:

```
   select :disabled.red{
   color: red;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of Javascript you can do something like this if there are no selected valid option:

```
<select class="">[options]</select>
```

And if there a selected valid option you simple put some class through javascript in the select element:

```
<select class="selected">[options]</select>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
select{
 color: [not selected color];
}
select.selected{
 color: [selected color];
}
```