# CSS how to change text color of disabled option inside a select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, html-select

I have the following selector:

```
<div id="cameraSourceWrap" class="settingRow adminShow">
  <select id="cameraSource" class="js-example-basic-single">
  </select>
</div>
```

In which I create the options in JS in a for loop:

```
 $('#cameraSource').append('<option id="camera' + i + '" class="optionC" value=' + i + '>' 
+ config.video.videoCapturer.devices[i] + '</option>');
```

Now I added inside my CSS file this:

```
.optionC {
color: blue;
}
.optionC:disabled {
color: red;
}
.optionC[disabled=disabled]{
color: red;
}
```

This is what I get inside the inspector:
[image: image of inspector in dev tools]

This is what it looks like:
[image: image of select on website]
Why aren't the views red for disabled? and blue for normal?

EDIT: I have also tried with this:
https://select2.github.io/
Which makes it look different, but still the option objects do not respond

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the 'option' color with the attribute 'disabled'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065920/change-the-option-color-with-the-attribute-disabled)

Comment: @Roberrrt - the problem with that duplicate is that none of the answers actually work :p

Comment: @Roberrrt Jaromanda is right, none of those answers work for my case

Comment: It seems OSX doesn't allow styling of `option` elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Simple Working Solution!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/wCFBw/954/)

It may be because since u add select option in js, js gets load after the css.

So u should add the color for select option in js or jquery. Please refer the code.

```
$("option.optionC").css("color","blue");
$("option.optionC:disabled").css("color","red");
```

Here is the Working [DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCFBw/954/).

Comment: This does not work. I added this lines both before and after creating the options programatically. And neither does the "color: red!important;" part work

Comment: Even in jsfiddle, with the link that you gave me, it is still gray for disabled:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/GewdBW2qnHVmvhQ/upload.png

Comment: are u using safar browser?

Comment: Chrome, and Chromium.
I need the change in colour to be valid inside a Android WebView.
So I am testing it inside Chrome, and inside the webview of a Nexus 7 Android 5.0 device.

Comment: In safari, your code, in jsfiddle, it changes the text color of the selected one. so $("select").css("color", "blue"); does work, but not the option ones. PS I'm on a Mac running Sierra 10.12. If it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [:disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) psuedo class in css.

```js
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   $('#cameraSource').append('<option id="camera' + i +
     '" class="optionC" value=' + i + '>check</option>');
     // make half of the options disabled for this example
     if(i%2===0){
      $('#camera'+i).attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
 }
```

```css
.optionC {
  color: blue;
}

.optionC:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cameraSourceWrap" class="settingRow adminShow">
  <select id="cameraSource" class="js-example-basic-single">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Still no red:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/GS9ID4rVtBnIvx0/upload.png

Answer (score -1):

You can try with "!Important".
Like this :

```
.optionC:disabled
{
color : red !important;
}
```

Comment: Please do not _ever_ suggest using !important.

Comment: Can you please tell me why ?